# Noda Time zone Format

Tags: c#, nodatime, datetime-conversion

I am using the Noda Time library. My code is

```
var timeZone = NodaTime.DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetZoneOrNull("Europe/Amsterdam");
```

above line of code gives me value like this which I don't want.

```
MaxOffset: +2:00
MinOffset: +00:19:32
```

when I use the same zone and query using the timezonedb.com its give me result like this

```
UTC/GMT +2.00 hours
```

But I need result in this format:

```
(UTC+02:00) Europe/Amsterdam
```

How can I achieve this using Noda Time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the result of the line of code you've given is a `DateTimeZone`. That *has* a `MinOffset` and a `MaxOffset`, but that's a different matter.

You can find out the current standard and wall offset using:

```
IClock clock = // some clock, e.g. SystemClock.Instance;
Instant now = clock.Now;
ZoneInterval interval = zone.GetZoneInterval(now);
Offset wallOffset = interval.WallOffset;
Offset standardOffset = interval.StandardOffset;
```

So depending on whether you want the `UTC+08:00` to represent the current standard or wall offset, you can format that. For example:

```
string text = string.Format("(UTC{0:+m}) {1}", interval.WallOffset, zone.Id);
```

Comment: well some how i end up on this 
 var properTimeZone = new ZonedDateTime(timeZone.AtLeniently(localDateTime).ToInstant(), timeZone).ToString("'('UTCo<G>')' z", null);

its giving me result in this format
(UTC+04:30) Asia/Kabul

Comment: is there any way to dynamically find out either UTC or GMT by using format which i mentioned above

Comment: please see my edit question now you will understand what i actually want using NODA time.

Comment: @HaseebKhan: What do you mean by "find out either UTC or GMT"? I've shown you how to get the current standard offset or wall offset...

Comment: var properTimeZone = new ZonedDateTime(timeZone.AtLeniently(localDateTime).ToInstant(), timeZone).ToString("'('UTCo<G>')' z", null

is this line of code is corrent to format the time zone?

Comment: @HaseebKhan: That's not an ideal way of doing it, as you really only want to format the offset, and you shouldn't need to perform any conversion from a *local* time at all - see my edit for how I'd do it.

Comment: @HaseebKhan - FYI - For all practical purposes, GMT and UTC are [essentially the same thing](http://codeofmatt.com/2014/06/18/utc-vs-gmt/).